# Clion + Docker Toolchain with Conan: Problem highlighting / linting problems including dependencies

Tags: c++, docker, clion, conan, toolchain

I developed a C++ project, and use Conan for my dependencies. I recently switched to also shipping a Dockerfile, for setting up a Docker toolchain in CLion to ease the setup for other developers who try to develop on the project on different platforms.

The Conan integration works fine, and it is possible to build & run the project.
However, the linting in CLion has problems; CLion does not correctly identify the dependencies that I install in the Dockerfile using Conan. I mapped the conan data dir to my host machine (primarily to avoid recompilation each time I reload the CMakeLists), but I don't know how / if I need to  adjust the CLion linter settings to also look inside that directory for the dependencies. Is it possible to adjust CLion's settings so that it is more convenient to develop, because no incorrect errors / warnings are shown?

Comment: This is all pretty vague what you're saying with little concrete info on what you did (not what you intended to achieve!) so it's hard to give an answer. Also, "more convenient" is going strongly in the opinion territory, which would be off-topic here.